# What is the difference between `balance`, `frozen_balance`, `staking_balance` and `delegated_balance`

Tags: rpc, staking-balance

In the [delegates RPC results](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/rpc.html#get-block-id-context-delegates-pkh) what is the difference between `balance`, `frozen_balance`, `staking_balance` and `delegated_balance`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [RPC descriptions in the documentations](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/rpc.html#get-block-id-context-delegates-pkh) are generally pretty self explanatory but let's try to clear it up by an example.

Say I have a tz account that I own with a total of 11000 XTZ. I bake with this account. My friend Bob who has 5000 XTZ in a KT address, he delegates his funds for me to bake for his behalf. Though inconsequential, we combine for 2 rolls (8000 XTZ per roll).

`balance` (my own balance) is `11000`

`delegated_balance` (how much I'm delegated, this case only from Bob) is `5000`

`staking_balance` (the total counted for my baking, including Bob's) is `16000`

Because I'm a baker, every time I bake a block or endorses, bonds are taken from my tz account and rewards are held. So imagine that I had made 10 endorsements and 1 block baked, bonds per endorsement and bake is 64 XTZ and 512 XTZ, its rewards are 2 XTZ and 16 XTZ, respectively.

bonds = `10 * 64 + 1 * 512 = 1152 XTZ`

rewards = `10 * 2 + 1 * 16 = 36 XTZ`

total frozen = `1152 + 36 = 1188 XTZ`

`frozen_balance` (all frozen bonds and rewards *[and fees]*) is `1188`

Note that because rewards are not counted towards your total balance until it is unlocked and bonds are still part of your balance (though inaccessible), your `balance` or `staking_balance` does not change even considering your bonds and rewards.